# Debugging into MFC header code does not work with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, mfc, pdb-files

**TL;DR**: Debuigging *into* MFC (`CString`) header code does not work on *both* my machines and as far as I can tell this is due to the peculiar way these headers are compiled.

Stepping through MFC header code when entered via disassembly works, but setting brealpoints does not work.

I'm looking for a workaround or at least acknowledgement of my analysis.

---

System:

- Visual Studio 2019 Professional 16.9.6
- Windows 10 / 1809 Enterprise LTSC

**Setup**: (I do apologize for this being rather long.)

- Create a Visual Studio 2019 Example MFC Application Project (SDI App)
- Make sure `Enable Just My Code`is **off** under Options -> Debugging -> General.
- Set the build configuration to Debug/x64 (does not make a difference, but let's all stay on the same page)
- Navigate to `MFCApplication1.cpp` -> `CMFCApplication1App::InitInstance()`
- Insert a CString init like this:

  ```
    ...
    InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

    CWinAppEx::InitInstance(); // please put breakpoint 1 here

    // Add this line and set breakpoints
    CString this_is_text(L"Debugging into CString Header does not work!"); // breakpoint 2 here
  ```

Now, you can start the program under the debugger, and you should stop at the first breakpoint:

[image: First breakpoint in InitInstance]

Now, **make sure all symbols are loaded**, easiest done via the Call Stack:

[image: Fully selected Call Stack with Context Menu and marked Load Symbols entry]

Just select all lines in the call stack window and hit Load Symbols in the context menu. Afterwards the call stack should look roughly like this:

```
     >  MFCApplication1.exe!CMFCApplication1App::InitInstance() Line 75 C++
        mfc140ud.dll!AfxWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance=0x00007ff7b5070000, ...) Line 37    C++
        MFCApplication1.exe!wWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance=0x00007ff7b5070000, ...) Line 26   C++
        MFCApplication1.exe!invoke_main() Line 123  C++
        MFCApplication1.exe!__scrt_common_main_seh() Line 288   C++
        MFCApplication1.exe!__scrt_common_main() Line 331   C++
        MFCApplication1.exe!wWinMainCRTStartup(void * __formal=0x000000c2b7084000) Line 17  C++
        kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  Unknown
        ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()  Unknown
```

Now, you can try *stepping-into* (possibly F11) the `CWinAppEx::InitInstance()` function, which should *work* without a problem, landing you in `mfc140ud.dll!CWinApp::InitInstance() Line 394` - this is OK.

Step out again, and then then try to step-into the `CString` ctor:

[image: Breakpoint at CString ctor]

This DOES NOT work on my machine(s)!

What I can do however, is (from the point above) switch to disassembly view, step into the `call`s there and get into the header code this way:

[image: Disassembly step into MFC header copde]

I can then successfully step through (but never into) the MFC header code. Trying to set a breakpoint will result in the error:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the debugger's code type is associated with this line.
> Possible causes include ...

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\atlmfc\include\cstringt.h`

[image: Breakpoint error]

And this is where I'm at.

**Analysis**:

What we can see from the MFC code is that we *can* step into "regular" cpp code, but as soon as we try to step into (or set breakpoint) code that is inside this `CStringt.h` it breaks.

Peculiar here: This is template *header* code, and still the executed code (as shown by the disassembly) is not in the user module but in the `mfc###.dll`! I think they do some clever tricks with the preprocessor (see `defined(_MFC_DLL_BLD)` and somesuch) which enables this multi use of the header file, and maybe, possibly this is also what breaks the debugger.

**Question**:

- Is this a known problem, does this happen with all VS2019 installs, is there something peculiar to my setup?
- Maybe fixed in a newer VS version?
- Iff this is actually broken, what would be a useable workaround, other than constantly switching to disassembly view when into the MFC headers.

The most interesting answer here would actually be as to WHY this breaks - where does the debugger get confused? Is this a general problem with re-`define`-ing code when debugging library code?

Comment: Martin, Are you using Visual Assist? If Yes, none of the solution will not work. Some of them will not work even if you are not using Visual Assist.

Comment: @JohnCz - yes, we use VSAssist. Not sure how that tool would come into pay wrt. breakpoints in the debugger though. Your comment has too many negatives. I failed to parse all the none ... not ;-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Analysis went sideways at some point, but we finally found one part of the problem here:

The `Require source files to exactly match the original version` option:

[image: Debugging General Option]

was the problem, but in a very peculiar way:

When you do NOT require source files to match (that is, disable this default option), then the erroneous behavior of the OP occurs: The debugger can no longer match the symbols to the `cstringt.h` file.

Unfortunately, I had this disabled on both machines. Pulling in a third machine showed that we could set breakpoints (though F11 still does not work) and by comparing the xml export of the VS settings we found that this was different.

So, long story short: For us, to be able to set breakpoints in the (unmodified!) MFC header, requires us to *enable* the `Require source files to exactly match ..` option.

If the option is disabled, which would imply a more lenient behavior by the debugger, it no longer works.

And, yes, we double checked it's always the same source file at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\atlmfc\include\cstringt.h`

The mystery with step-into/F11 persists, but I guess this would better be taken to a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

The source shipped with MSVC does not match.

I think this happen, as DLLs got updated with Windows Update or a new vcredist, but Visual Studio includes are not updated. If you build with `/MT` or `/MTd` and link MFC statically, the problem does not persist.

Probably this can be reported to http://developercommunity.visualstudio.com if you care.

**Workaround 1**

Do steps described by @selbie:

> 1. Set a breakpoint on the line of code I want to step into.
> 2. When
>    the breakpoint is reached, right click in the editor window and select
>    "Go To Disassemly".
> 3. In disassembly mode, step over until you get to
>    a `call` statement. [...] You
>    can flip out of disassembly mode by right-clicking again and selecting
>    "go to source code".

<sub>(skipped the part not relevant to this issue)</sub>

Then pick up the location of the header manually, the debugger will tell that it does not match. The difference seem to be insignificant though, so the header is usable.

**Workaround 2**

Link MFC statically, compile with `/MT` or `/MTd`

**Workaround 3**

ATL has a similar `CString` that does not suffer from the issue:

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlstr.h>

int main() {
    ATL::CString this_is_text("Debugging into CString header works");
}
```

Comment: I would be surprised if MFC's support libraries were to be updated with Windows Update. Have you verified this to be the case? I'm leaning towards MFC's `CString` implementation confusing Visual Studio's debugger due to a mix of preprocessor macros and class templates.

Comment: @IInspectable, maybe not with Windows Updates, but sure with visual studio redistributables. I don't think debugger is confused by templates as static linking fixes the issue, and CString is not the most contrived part, comparing to some standard library parts, like `std::function`/`std::bind`. (Debugger itself does not parse anything, it relies on .pdb file and line numbers / identifier names in it)

Comment: I thought you always need `/MTd` for debug step in to MFC. Is that specific for some VS versions and/or some classes?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, apparently yes, some combinations work with `/MDd` / `/MD`. And sure `/MT` just works like `/MTd`.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the Enable Just My Code option in Tools->Options->Debugging

[image]

I know that works for c++ std:: library code debugging. The other technique I do, when I forget to uncheck this option, is similar to what you describe above.

1. Set a breakpoint on the line of code I want to step into.
2. When the breakpoint is reached, right click in the editor window and select "Go To Disassemly".
3. In disassembly mode, step over until you get to a `call` statement. That's typically the std library.  Eventually, you'll navigate into a mix of assembly and system code sources. You can flip out of disassembly mode by right-clicking again and selecting "go to source code".

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: The "difference" are NOT just tied to CString... I am aving the same type of problem [with VS-2019 and latest updates] string to step into CDialog::DoModal()...

With the "Exact match" disabled, it steps to some 'random line'... with it enabled it  prompts for a source file....

So how do we get these to MATCH??/

Comment: your post is not an answer, but a separate question. As you can see above, my problem was partly solved by enabling the option. I guess you would have to start a new question with our own specifics.